# Trouble with dynamic array of timage and tlabel in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to add an attachment, and have the form grow longer each time an attachment is added, to make room for a line that holds information about the attachment with a label and some 16X16 images. For this I chose to use a dynamic array (not sure whether that's best). each time an attachment is added, I want to create a new instance of these objects. My code doesn't seem to work. what's wrong with the follwing code?

```
procedure TVisionMail.AddAttachment(FileString: String);
var
I: Integer;
begin
     AttCount := AttCount + 1; // increment attachment count

     //set attachment file name
     if (AttCount <> 0) and (edAttachment.Text <> '') then
       edAttachment.text := edAttachment.text + ';';
     edAttachment.text := edAttachment.text + FileString;

     //move objects position down to allow space for attachment line
     VisionMail.Height := VisionMail.Height + 25;
     Panel1.Height     := Panel1.Height + 25;
     btnSend.Top       := btnSend.Top + 25;
     btnExit.Top       := btnExit.Top + 25;
     StatusMemo.Top    := StatusMemo.Top + 25;
     Memo1.Top         := Memo1.Top + 25;
     lblBody.Top       := lblBody.Top + 25;

       //Allocate memory for arrays
       SetLength(newImg, AttCount);
       SetLength(newlbl, AttCount);
       SetLength(newDel, AttCount);
       SetLength(newPin, AttCount);

        //create new instance and set parents, positions, color, events
        newImg[AttCount]:= TImage.Create(VisionMail);
        with newImg[AttCount] do
        begin
              Parent     := Panel1;
              Top        := Memo1.Top - 25;
              Left       := 408;
              Height     := 16;
              Width      := 16;
        end;
        newlbl[AttCount]:= TLabel.Create(VisionMail);
        with newlbl[AttCount] do
        begin
              Parent     := Panel1;
              Top        := newImg[I].Top + 2;
              Left       := 397;
              Height     := 3;
              Width      := 13;
              BiDiMode   := bdRightToLeft;
       end;
       newDel[AttCount] := TAdvToolButton.Create(VisionMail);
       with newDel[AttCount] do
        begin
              Parent       := Panel1;
              Top          := newImg[I].Top;
              Left         := 440;
              Height       := 16;
              Width        := 16;
              color        := clBtnFace;
              colorChecked := clBtnFace;
              colorDown    := clBtnFace;
              colorHot     := clBtnFace;
              OnClick      := btnDelAttClick;
              OnMouseEnter := btnDelAttMouseEnter;
              OnMouseLeave := btnDelAttMouseLeave;
       end;
       newPin[AttCount] := TImage.Create(VisionMail);
       with newDel[AttCount] do
        begin
              Parent     := Panel1;
              Top        := newImg[I].Top;
              Left       := 425;
              Height     := 16;
              Width      := 16;
       end;
       //get Icon for extension of file
       lstIcons.GetBitmap(GetIcon(ExtractFileExt
                          (OpenDialog1.FileName)),
                          newImg[AttCount].Picture.Bitmap);
       newlbl[AttCount].Caption    := ExtractFileName(FileString);

end;
```

Comment: Your data structure is all wrong. You need a record to hold the 4 components. And then `TList<T>` to hold all the records.

Comment: Now, you also state "my code doesn't seem to work". That is no use to us. You have to describe how it fails. Explain precisely what you expect of your code, and in what way it fails to meet that expectation. This will take you more time. And save us time. That is how it must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious flaw is that you are writing off the end of all of your arrays. For example, you write

```
SetLength(newImg, AttCount);
```

and that means that the valid indices for `newImg` are `0` to `AttCount-1` inclusive. But then you write

```
newImg[AttCount] := ...
```

and that is an out of bounds access because the last index is `AttCount-1`. You do the same for all your array access.

If you compile with range checking enabled, the compiler will generate a runtime error that explains what you have done wrong.

Personally I think you would be better using a record to hold your four components:

```
TAttachmentControls = record
  Img: TImage;
  Lbl: TLabel;
  .. etc.
end;
```

And use a `TList<TAttachmentControls>` as your container.